# How I export my Firebase data in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want my Firebase database in Excel sheets. I have all these children: `Names`, `Branch`, `Batch`, `College` as attributes of all users. I want to export these in Excel Sheets.

Here's an example of items in the database:

[image: Firebase Database]

And this is how I want the Excel Sheet to look:

[image: Excel Sheet]

Answer (score 40):

Export your firebase to JSON. Just click the settings on the right of your database.

[image]

Then, convert the JSON to CSV. There are a lot of csv converter online. You can try https://json-csv.com/. Save the csv and open with Excel.

Comment: Is this all things are possible programmatically?

Comment: Where is this view into the settings to the right of the database? Is it in the firebase console? I don't see it, or perhaps the UI updated. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7kf1va045k5ohwz/Screenshot%202018-09-23%2022.17.51.png?dl=0

Comment: Sadly it's for the Realtime Database only. For that, it's still there.

Comment: i have a json format like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/15OUvKo1ywQRF6qdbHmPg91Gx1Lt2tWXY/view?usp=sharing and its not able to convert into csv properly

Answer (score 3):

I would like to explain more Since its unclear to some people. 
Step 1. Select Realtime Database (You won't find any download button in Cloud Firestore). for that, Select Database > Realtime Database
[image]

Step 2. In there, you'll find a three-dotted button in the right top corner. Select your option (Import/ Export)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the firebase database, you can see export to JSON file, When you export it download it and then use an online converter to change to excel file.

Comment: Once you have a JSON file you can use excel power query to import from JSON File.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here are mentioning online converter tools. You can also use Excel's built-in data importer. I found it useful when I have to export it in a excel table.

Say I have the following data:
[image]

Similar like other answers, click the triple dot > Export JSON..

Then, open Excel. Go to Data > Get Data > From File... > From JSON

[image: Import JSON]

Then, click on **Into Table**

[image: Into table]

Click, **Close and Load**

[image: CLose & load]

Result:

[image: Result excel]